# Project not compiling with no warnings or errors in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, antivirus

I am going trough the book *C Programming: A Modern Approach* (KN King) and I am on chapter 2. I have done almost every exercise and program, but I have trouble with program #7.

Basically, it asks you to write a program that calculates the minimum amount of dollar bills you need for a specific amount. I have written the program and it works fine for bills of 20, 10, 5 and 1. But if I copy part of the code to use it for $50 bills, the file won't compile.

Here is my code:

```
int x, num, rest ;
printf("Insert amount to pay: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("You will use the least amount of bills if you pay like so: \n");

num = x / 50;
rest = x - num * 50;
printf("$%d bills: %d\n", 50, num);

/*
num = rest / 20;
rest = rest - num * 20;
printf("$%d bills: %d\n", 20, num);
*/

num = rest / 10;
rest = rest - num * 10;
printf("$%d bills: %d\n", 10, num);

num = rest / 5;
rest = rest - num * 5;
printf("$%d bills: %d\n", 5, num);

num = rest;
printf("$%d bills: %d\n", 1, num);

return 0;
```

The program works perfectly, until I try to use the part I commented out (it is a copy of the other blocks, but with a number 20 instead of 10 for example).

The compiler gives no warnings or errors, it just won't compile. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean no warnings or errors? What happens when you try to compile?

Comment: The build log in Code:block shows this:

But the terminal window that usually shows up does not apear.

-------------- Build: Debug in p_5 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\p_5.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: That doesn't mean it didn't compile. That means it compiled and ran to completion with no errors.

Comment: But it behaves differently if i try to use the commented part because it shows nothing. If i comment or delete any part after the $50 bill it works and i can input and number and it prints out the results.

If i use also the commented part it shows nothing...

Comment: I compiled that (copied into a `main()`) and it worked perfectly. I restored the $20 section and it worked even better.

Comment: How did you compile it? I swear i have tripple checked everything but it doesnt work if i ad the code for a fifth bill :/

Comment: MS Visual C from command line with my usual typically simple Makefile.

Comment: Well thanks a lot Wather vane for testing my code at least i know it should work :)
But i still dont know why this doesnt work for me :/
I have copied the code in a new project but it stil doesnt work. After pressing build and run if says: "It looks like the project hasnt been build yet" ad if i press yes to build it it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was totally not C related as the code did in fact compile and try to run.

It turns out my antivirus blocked the .exe form running or something like that. I have no idea how and why in the world it would do it, but it did. As i disabled "Avast Free Antivirus" the code worked like a charm.

Thanks to Wather Vane for testing my code. You made me belive I didn't go insane yet :)